# .NET Sybase AseCommand pass Hex string and store in database

Tags: c#, .net, database, sybase, ase

Currently we are executing stored procedure with hex string from .NET

```
command.executequery("exec spname 
x092837x737")
```

No single quote in string parameter.

We want to change it to

```
command.text = "spname"
command.parameters.add("x09283x737")
command.executequery()
```

Problem here is .NET considering parameter as string but not actual hex. Is there a way we can add parameters like below

```
command.parameters.add(x09283x737)
```

Without double quote.

Is it possible in .NET

Comment: Try :            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("spname", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            parameter.Value = 0x092837;

Comment: Thanks for your reply but its not number its hex text, any other way

Comment: Than change type to varchar.

Comment: Ya but value string 0x092837 getting compile time error in .net

Comment: Because when you change type to string you also have to put double quotes around the value.

Comment: Yes that is the problem i am facing... What can be done on this..there is no data type i found in .net to handle this.

Comment: The System.Data.SqlDbType should match the type in the database.

Comment: I am giving it NVarchar in database but its not able to find out if its string or hex

Comment: You have a string which is NVARCHAR.  It is not hex if the database defines NVARCHAR.

Comment: In sybase hex string can be assigned to nvarchar datatype like below
Declare @data nvarchar = x097372

Comment: It is not HEX.  It is nvarchar which is a string.SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("spname", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar); SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter); parameter.Value = "0x092837";